# How do I use two different versions of OpenCV in one application?

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

To get it out of the way, here's my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
include B:/Android/OpenCV/Libraries/OpenCVModified/install/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl
LOCAL_MODULE     := detection_based_tracker
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
include B:/Android/OpenCV/Libraries/OpenCVOriginal/install/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := DetectionBasedTrackerOriginal_jni.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl
LOCAL_MODULE     := detection_based_tracker_original
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libavcodec
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libprebuilt/libavcodec.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libavformat
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libprebuilt/libavformat.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libavutil
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libprebuilt/libavutil.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libswscale
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libprebuilt/libswscale.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libffmpeg_mediametadataretriever_jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libprebuilt/libffmpeg_mediametadataretriever_jni.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I have an assingment, where I have to modify OpenCV slightly to speed it up. I want to demonstrate the effects of the changes I've made in one application that uses the original and the modified versions of OpenCV at the same time.

I've already made wrappers and implemented them successfully in the application and the application calls the correct underlying JNI code for each wrapper.

The problem is, that the modules seem to be using only one OpenCV source. It seems to be the one that's included first, if I compile the modified DBT first, it's the modified one and if I compile the original one (after cleaning project) it's the original OpenCV.

I have logcat logs that confirm that the JNI parts are separated correctly, but the OpenCV is uniform for both wrappers.

So what I need to do is get NDK to install both versions of OpenCV and make the modules to use the correct versions, except I have no idea how.

Comment: why not separate into two projects?

Comment: I could, and I will, if I don't find a solution to this, but I'd rather have it in a single application and switch between the two on the fly.

Comment: how? using a different namespace for the custom one?

Comment: No, just making two separate wrappers for each of the libraries used. So at the Java part I have two different classes and two different objects and an if clause to choose which one to use for detection, based on a setting.